# Javascript - moving multiple images inside a div, with border control

Tags: javascript, html, image

Little premise: I didn't want to make this question, because I thought it was a too personal and generic problem; but after 2 days without any improvement, I couldn't resist anymore.

So basically, my project is an aquarium with multiple fishes inside.
It all works fine, the only problem is that, in short words: the first fish image remains inside the div(it even stops too soon), the second one arrives a bit farther, the third even farther, and so on.
The opposite thing happens with the top margin: going forward, the last fish is always farther from the margin, and I can't find out the reason.
My scope is to keep all the fishes inside the "acquario" div (which has the black borders).
P.S. With sx and dx margins, they have no problem.

```js
var BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT = 7;
var BORDER_TOP_DOWN = 28;
var fishes = new Array();
var nextId = 0;
var heightMax;
var widthMax;
var n; //initial direction, see createFish()

init();
/* light blue fish (dory, to clarify)*/
createFish("https://s18.postimg.org/n8sqmtjkp/pesce1_sx.png", "https://s30.postimg.org/6w8xyqwep/pesce1_dx.png");
/* white and yellow fish */
createFish("https://s28.postimg.org/6aalv0pst/pesce2_sx.png", "https://s29.postimg.org/dxbi0vypz/pesce2_dx.png");
/* dark blue fish */
createFish("https://s24.postimg.org/sbgt8zn6t/pesce3_sx.png", "https://s29.postimg.org/v65opob7r/pesce3_dx.png");
/* white-blue-yellow fish */
createFish("https://s30.postimg.org/62lb9bfwx/pesce4_sx.png", "https://s28.postimg.org/kt5m4ea65/pesce4_dx.png");
/* orange fish */
createFish("https://s18.postimg.org/q5sq0saex/pesce5_sx.png", "https://s18.postimg.org/uqnwe2vex/pesce5_dx.png");
showFishes();

function init() {

  heightMax = document.getElementById("acquario").clientHeight - BORDER_TOP_DOWN;
  widthMax = document.getElementById("acquario").clientWidth - BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT;
  n = 1;
}

function createFish(src1, src2) {
  imgFishSX = new Image();
  imgFishDX = new Image();
  imgFishSX.src = src1;
  imgFishDX.src = src2;
  n *= -1;
  var fish = {
    id: nextId,
    /* default x position: random number between 1 and widthMax */
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * widthMax - imgFishSX.width) + 1),
    /* default y position: random number between 1 and heightMax */
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * heightMax - imgFishSX.height) + 1),
    xIncrease: n * getIncrease(),
    yIncrease: n * getIncrease(),
    imageSX: imgFishSX,
    imageDX: imgFishDX
  };
  addFishToArray((fish));
  nextId++;
}

function addFishToArray(fish) {
  fishes.push(fish);
}

function showFishes() {
  var node = document.getElementById("acquario");
  var stringToInner = "";
  var src;
  /* first, we make the string with all the img filled in */
  for (var i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
    /* we have to check if the default increase direction was <-- or --> */
    fishes[i].xIncrease > 0 ? src = fishes[i].imageSX.src : src = fishes[i].imageDX.src;
    /* z-index --> overlap priority */
    stringToInner += "<img src =\"" + src +
      "\" id=\"" + fishes[i].id + "\" style= \"margin-left: " +
      fishes[i].x + "px;margin-top: " + fishes[i].y + "px;z-index: " +
      fishes[i].id + ";position: absolute;\">";
    stringToInner += "<br>";
  }

  /* then, we insert it */
  node.innerHTML = stringToInner;

  /* let's raise hell! */
  moveFishes();
}

function getIncrease() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
}

function moveFishes() {

  /* scroll the array: we need to check each fish one by one */
  for (var i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
    moveFish(fishes[i]);
  }
  /* infinite loop */
  setTimeout(function() {
    moveFishes()
  }, 50);
}

function moveFish(fish) {
  /* with this node, I'll apply changes to my html document */
  node = document.getElementById(fish.id);
  /* we are inside, just move */
  if (fish.x > 0 && fish.x < widthMax - node.width && fish.y > 0 && fish.y < heightMax - node.height) {
    node.style.marginLeft = fish.x + "px";
    node.style.marginTop = fish.y + "px";
    fish.x += fish.xIncrease;
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
    /* too --> , we need to get <-- */
  } else if (fish.x >= widthMax - node.width) {
    node.src = fish.imageDX.src;
    fish.xIncrease = -getIncrease();
    fish.x += fish.xIncrease;
    /* too <-- , we need to get --> */
  } else if (fish.x <= 0) {
    node.src = fish.imageSX.src;
    fish.xIncrease = 5;
    fish.x += getIncrease();
    /* too up, we need to get down */
  } else if (fish.y >= heightMax - node.height) {
    fish.yIncrease = -getIncrease();
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
    /* too down, we need to get up */
  } else if (fish.y <= 0) {
    fish.yIncrease = getIncrease();
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
html {
  background: url("https://s24.postimg.org/rakxoa7sl/sfondo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkibact-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#acquario {
  border-bottom: 28px solid black;
  border-top: 28px solid black;
  border-right: 7px solid black;
  border-left: 7px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="acquario">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just asking, could you not just use a `canvas` element instead?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned it, but I'm new with HTML and didn't know about the canvas element. You think it suits for my case?

Comment: The `canvas` tag is a much better element to use for displaying graphics which move around and manipulate, I will create you a simple example soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want the fishes to bound off the walls or to hide under the wall? and why do you use margin-left and margin-top instead of top and left properties? it makes the aquarium scrolling. Is it ok now?

```js
var BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT = 7;
var BORDER_TOP_DOWN = 28;
var fishes = new Array();
var nextId = 0;
var heightMax;
var widthMax;
var n; //initial direction, see createFish()

init();
/* light blue fish (dory, to clarify)*/
createFish("https://s18.postimg.org/n8sqmtjkp/pesce1_sx.png", "https://s30.postimg.org/6w8xyqwep/pesce1_dx.png");
/* white and yellow fish */
createFish("https://s28.postimg.org/6aalv0pst/pesce2_sx.png", "https://s29.postimg.org/dxbi0vypz/pesce2_dx.png");
/* dark blue fish */
createFish("https://s24.postimg.org/sbgt8zn6t/pesce3_sx.png", "https://s29.postimg.org/v65opob7r/pesce3_dx.png");
/* white-blue-yellow fish */
createFish("https://s30.postimg.org/62lb9bfwx/pesce4_sx.png", "https://s28.postimg.org/kt5m4ea65/pesce4_dx.png");
/* orange fish */
createFish("https://s18.postimg.org/q5sq0saex/pesce5_sx.png", "https://s18.postimg.org/uqnwe2vex/pesce5_dx.png");
showFishes();

function init() {

  heightMax = document.getElementById("acquario").clientHeight + BORDER_TOP_DOWN;
  widthMax = document.getElementById("acquario").clientWidth + BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT;
  n = 1;
}

function createFish(src1, src2) {
  imgFishSX = new Image();
  imgFishDX = new Image();
  imgFishSX.src = src1;
  imgFishDX.src = src2;
  n *= -1;
  var fish = {
    id: nextId,
    /* default x position: random number between 1 and widthMax */
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * (widthMax - BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT - imgFishSX.width)) + BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT),
    /* default y position: random number between 1 and heightMax */
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * (heightMax - BORDER_TOP_DOWN - imgFishSX.height)) + BORDER_TOP_DOWN),
    xIncrease: n * getIncrease(),
    yIncrease: n * getIncrease(),
    imageSX: imgFishSX,
    imageDX: imgFishDX
  };
  addFishToArray((fish));
  nextId++;
}

function addFishToArray(fish) {
  fishes.push(fish);
}

function showFishes() {
  var node = document.getElementById("acquario");
  var stringToInner = "";
  var src;
  /* first, we make the string with all the img filled in */
  for (var i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
    /* we have to check if the default increase direction was <-- or --> */
    fishes[i].xIncrease > 0 ? src = fishes[i].imageSX.src : src = fishes[i].imageDX.src;
    /* z-index --> overlap priority */
    stringToInner += "<img src =\"" + src +
      "\" id=\"" + fishes[i].id + "\" style= \"left: " +
      fishes[i].x + "px;top: " + fishes[i].y + "px;z-index: " +
      fishes[i].id + ";position: absolute;\">";
    stringToInner += "<br>";
  }

  /* then, we insert it */
  node.innerHTML = stringToInner;


  /* let's raise hell! */
  moveFishes();
}

function getIncrease() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
}

function moveFishes() {

  /* scroll the array: we need to check each fish one by one */
  for (var i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
    moveFish(fishes[i]);
  }
  /* infinite loop */
  setTimeout(function() {
    moveFishes()
  }, 50);
}

function moveFish(fish) {
  /* with this node, I'll apply changes to my html document */
  node = document.getElementById(fish.id);
  /* we are inside, just move */
  if (fish.x > BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT && fish.x < widthMax - node.width && fish.y > BORDER_TOP_DOWN && fish.y < heightMax - node.height) {
    node.style.left = fish.x + "px";
    node.style.top = fish.y + "px";
    fish.x += fish.xIncrease;
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
    /* too --> , we need to get <-- */
  } else if (fish.x >= widthMax - node.width) {
    node.src = fish.imageDX.src;
    fish.xIncrease = -getIncrease();
    fish.x += fish.xIncrease;
    /* too <-- , we need to get --> */
  } else if (fish.x <= BORDER_LEFT_RIGHT) {
    node.src = fish.imageSX.src;
    fish.xIncrease = 5;
    fish.x += getIncrease();
    /* too up, we need to get down */
  } else if (fish.y >= heightMax - node.height) {
    fish.yIncrease = -getIncrease();
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
    /* too down, we need to get up */
  } else if (fish.y <= BORDER_TOP_DOWN) {
    fish.yIncrease = getIncrease();
    fish.y += fish.yIncrease;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
html {
  background: url("https://s24.postimg.org/rakxoa7sl/sfondo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkibact-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#acquario {
  border-bottom: 28px solid black;
  border-top: 28px solid black;
  border-right: 7px solid black;
  border-left: 7px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="acquario">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: First: thanks for your time. Second: my scope is to keep all the fishes inside the "acquario" div (which has the black borders), and with top and left I can't do it: they go out.

Comment: so do you want the fishes no to swim on black border but bound at the edge of blue water and black border?

Comment: how about now? I changed the plus/minus signs in 24 and 25 line equation and inserted borderTopBottom and bortedLeftRight in 98 109 118 line instead of 0.

Comment: it works! I don't know how to thank you! you did it in just 20 mins... great work, really appreciate it mate.

Comment: I've also noticed that random start position of fishes is outside the water so I EDITED line 38 and 40 to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I know Pawel has fixed your issue, but I did state I would provide a canvas version so here it is

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/zh0b7zrj/1/

HTML :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

CSS :

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var backgroundImage = new Image();
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; //document.width is obsolete
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight; //document.height is obsolete

// Fish
function FishObject(xSet, ySet, xSpeed, ySpeed, spriteUrlRight, spriteUrlLeft) {
  this.XPos = xSet;
  this.YPos = ySet;
  this.XDefaultSpeed = xSpeed;
  this.YDefaultSpeed = ySpeed;
  this.xSpeed = this.XDefaultSpeed;
  this.ySpeed = this.YDefaultSpeed;
  this.RightSprite = new Image();
  this.RightSprite.src = spriteUrlRight;
  this.LeftSprite = new Image();
  this.LeftSprite.src = spriteUrlLeft;
}

FishObject.prototype.Draw = function(ctx) {
  if (this.xSpeed > 0) {
    ctx.drawImage(this.RightSprite, this.XPos, this.YPos);
  } else {
    ctx.drawImage(this.LeftSprite, this.XPos, this.YPos);
  }
}

FishObject.prototype.Update = function(ctx) {
  this.XPos += this.xSpeed;
  this.YPos += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.XPos <= 0) {
    this.xSpeed = this.XDefaultSpeed;
  } else if ((this.XPos + this.RightSprite.width) >= canvas.width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.XDefaultSpeed;
  }

  if (this.YPos <= 0) {
    this.ySpeed = this.YDefaultSpeed;
  } else if ((this.YPos + this.RightSprite.height) >= canvas.height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.YDefaultSpeed;
  }
}

backgroundImage.src = 'https://s24.postimg.org/rakxoa7sl/sfondo.jpg';

var Fishs = [];
Fishs.push(new FishObject(0, 0, 1, 1, "https://s18.postimg.org/n8sqmtjkp/pesce1_sx.png",
  "https://s30.postimg.org/6w8xyqwep/pesce1_dx.png"));
Fishs.push(new FishObject(0, 0, 2, 1.2, "https://s28.postimg.org/6aalv0pst/pesce2_sx.png",
  "https://s29.postimg.org/dxbi0vypz/pesce2_dx.png"));
Fishs.push(new FishObject(0, 0, 1.7, 2.8, "https://s24.postimg.org/sbgt8zn6t/pesce3_sx.png",
  "https://s29.postimg.org/v65opob7r/pesce3_dx.png"));
Fishs.push(new FishObject(0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, "https://s30.postimg.org/62lb9bfwx/pesce4_sx.png",
  "https://s28.postimg.org/kt5m4ea65/pesce4_dx.png"));
Fishs.push(new FishObject(0, 0, 0.7, 0.1, "https://s18.postimg.org/q5sq0saex/pesce5_sx.png",
  "https://s18.postimg.org/uqnwe2vex/pesce5_dx.png"));

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < Fishs.length; i++) {
    var fishObject = Fishs[i];
    fishObject.Draw(ctx);
    fishObject.Update(ctx);
  }

}, (1000 / 60)); // 60 FPS (frames per second)
```